# Qt QML font point size not matching multiple devices

Tags: qt, fonts, qml

I have a QtQuick app where the font is 14 points.
On Windows it renders well (0,5 cm circa) but on my Android phone the size is way smaller.
Why? I knew that point size render with same size on every screen.
I've also set the AA_EnableHighDpiScaling variable but nothing changed.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are significant differences with how different platforms report logical DPI (what's used to determine the actual rendering size of a font with a specified point size). As a result, a "point" may or may not match the reality of 1/72 of an inch on any particular display of any device.

This represents a choice by the platform implementers (Microsoft, Apple, Google, etc) to implement a text rendering style over implementing 1 point = 1/72 of an inch. Qt is forced to compromise between the platforms' style choices and a programming model that is suitably cross-platform.

In other words, measuring the actual size of text rendered in a font with a point size is rarely going to match between different devices and displays let alone different platforms.

More details here:

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-32096

As suggested there, you are best off using a pixel size for your fonts so that it looks correct relative to other UI elements which are always drawn in pixel sizes.